# Why do I get this 404 error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In a newly created MVC4 application, insert this function in the account controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult AdminLogin(AdminLoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login("administrator", model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
        {
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The password provided is incorrect.");
        return View(model);
    }
```

and this

```
public class AdminLoginModel
{ 
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

is put into the accountModel.cs. I also created a new file AdminLogin.cshtml and leave it empty. 
In the _loginPartial.cshtml file I insert an action link

`<li>@Html.ActionLink("Register", "AdminLogin", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" })</li>`

But when I click that Register link, I then see the 404 error stating that 
`/Account/AdminLogin` is not found.

I miss something along the way inserting that tiny mvc; could you help me ? I am a mvc beginner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clicking a link in a browser results in a GET request, but your action method is only available for POST requests.

Add the `[HttpGet]` attribute or remove the `[HttpPost]` attribute to resolve this particular problem.

In general you will want to keep using POST requests when submitting data. As such, my recommendation would be to change the client side to use a form (or use client side logic to intercept the link click action and submit the data using an ajax request).

Comment: Awesome! thank you, in the function above, there is `returnUrl`; would you please also explain me what it is for actually ?

Comment: @BéVúSữa1 The returnUrl is an additional parameter that indicates where you should send the user if login succeeds. If users go directly to a protected page (requiring login), this information allows you to know where they wanted to go so you can send them there after login.