# Redirect to new LoginPage fails

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Continuing from [Why do I get this 404 error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14666122/why-do-i-get-this-404-error)

it is strange to me that once I click the link to visit AdminLogin Page, it directs me to the login page instead (AdminLogin and Login pages are different in my case). The URL later becomes
`http://localhost:1390/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fAccount%2fAdminLogin`

I thought it should be `http://localhost:1390/Account/AdminLogin`

Comment: have you created deployable dependancies in your MVC project?

Comment: also, is your 'AdminLogin' Action sealed with an [authorize] attribute?

Comment: If you have an [authorize] attribute protecting you AdminLogin Action, then no unauthenticated user can reach the method. Meaning no user can login. That method must be left open for anonymous users.

Comment: What is "deployable dependencies" ? ANd yes I have that attribute over the methods. But if I remove it, I still run into the same issue

Comment: "deployable dependancies" are necessary in many cases for deploying an MVC web app. Standard IIS with .NET 4.0 doesn't come with MVC 3 libraries. These dependancies are a bin-style library setup through your solution explorer. This often has a side-effect of redirecting un-aothenticated users who visit an [authorize] page to a "~/account/login" page

Comment: you don't want to have an [authorize] tag applied to your login method. If you do, no unauthenticated user will be able to reach it, ergo, they will not be able to login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your AdminLogin action method is 'closed off' with an [Authorize] attribute, no user will be able to login.

Make this Action Method available to any user.